# Encrypt traffic between traefik and ingress in kubernetes cluster

Tags: encryption, kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress

I'm looking for solution how to encrypt traffic between Traefik frontend to kubernetes Ingress resource serving multiple application. The examples on internet, e.g. [1], show how to enable TLS support in Traefik or even use Let's Encrypt for Traefik and Ingress controller [2]. The problem is that all of them pass HTTPs request from frontend to HTTP backend. What I'm looking for is end-to-end encryption between frontend and backends.

I enabled TLS in Traefik as shown in [1], I enabled TLS in Ingress as shown [3], but still all traffic goes from HTTPs to HTTP. And, I don't know who is responsible for this decision (where it should be configured) the Traefik or Ingress.

Any suggestions?

1. https://medium.com/@patrickeasters/using-traefik-with-tls-on-kubernetes-cb67fb43a948
2. https://blog.osones.com/en/kubernetes-ingress-controller-with-traefik-and-lets-encrypt.html
3. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm trying to find the same solution.

Comment: Turns out it was an issue with traefik itself. Here are two tickets which address it: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3052 and https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/4048